# XmlRpcException while passing params to the ejabberd command

Tags: java, ejabberd, xml-rpc

I am trying to call the Ejabberd command `create_room_with_opts` via XMLRPC using the apache XMLRPC api. The following is the code I am using.

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL(<EJABBERD_HOST_URL>));
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setConfig(config);
// Command string
String command = "create_room_with_opts";

Map<String, Object> struct1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
struct1.put("user", <ADMIN_USERNAME>);
struct1.put("server", <HOST>);
struct1.put("password", <ADMIN_PASSWORD>);
struct1.put("admin", Boolean.TRUE);

Map<String, Object> struct = new HashMap<String, Object>();
struct.put("name", "testroom");
struct.put("service", <NAME_OF_SERVICE>);
struct.put("host", <HOST>);
struct.put("options", getOpts());

HashMap result = (HashMap) client.execute(command, params);
```

---

```
static Object[] getOpts() {
    Object opt[] = new Object[1];
    HashMap<String, Object> option = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    HashMap<String, Object> optionTuple = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    option.put("name", "public");
    option.put("value", Boolean.TRUE);
    optionTuple.put("option", option);

    return opt;
}
```

However, when I run this code I get the following exception.

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Error -122
Parameter '{struct,[{name,<<"public">>},{value,<<"true">>}]}' can't be coerced to type '{tuple,[{name,binary},{value,binary}]}'
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:181)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:149)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:95)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:39)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:53)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:166)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:136)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:125)
```

---

I am unable to identify the problem in this code.

I have tried the example given in the ejabberd documentation at the [API-Documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/),
but it seems that there is a syntax error in that example.

---

I am able to call the other commands(for example `create_room`, `register`, etc) for the same Ejabberd server successfully, so I know that the configuration is correct.

I am using **JDK1.7** and apache XMLRPC api 3.1.3

Is there any other example(for `create_room_with_opts` command) which I can check.

Comment: Issue also has been listed here: https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/28688/xmlrpcexception-while-passing-params-createroomwithopts-command

Comment: how have you created your params ?